# Finding the right DRIVER string for pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc

How do I find which DRIVER string to use with pyodbc? I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database.
The [connection documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings) isn't very specific about how to go about this.
I'm on OSX 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must have Oracle drivers installed on your machine. Then, on your system you can create DSN (Data Source Name). I see that there if free OSX ODBC manager. I hope you can create DSN with it and then you can use it like:

```
pyodbc.connect('DSN=my_dsn;uid=username;pwd=secretpassword')
```

If this works well and you want to omit DSN you can use more fancy Oracle connect string for ODBC which be found at: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/